# What kind of SSL do I have?

Tags: https

I am maintaining a site for someone.  He needs to know what type of SSL the site has because that data has to submitted to his bank.

I've never been asked such a question.  I have cpanel access. But I don't know how to figure out what "type" of ssl is installed.  Is there a way to print a report and give that to the bank?  I thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Is the reason behind this question for PCI Compliance purposes?

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the secure section of the site, you should be able to see the padlock icon the browser address bar. Click on that and you should be able to view the certificate information. You can copy that and send it to the bank.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/) will help you to know whether you have a certificate. SSL (secure socket layer) relies on having a certificate. It is the HTTPS instead of simple HTTP. You should have set up a certificate if you have SSL if not then you probably do not have SSL. (bad if you deal with money on the site)